# FirebaseUi - Swift - Cast value of UITableViewCell to custom class

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebaseui

I have an issue when working with a custom class for the `UITableViewCell` with Firebase-UI. Here is my code:

In my `TableViewController`:

```
self.dataSource = FirebaseTableViewDataSource(ref: firebaseRef, cellClass: MyEventTableViewCell.self, cellReuseIdentifier: "MyEventTableViewCell", view: self.tableView)

self.dataSource.populateCellWithBlock { (cell, obj) -> Void in

    let snap = obj as! FDataSnapshot
    print(cell)

    let myEventCell = cell as! MyEventTableViewCell

    myEventCell.eventNameLabel.text = "hello" 
}
```

In my `MyEventTableViewCell`:

```
class MyEventTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var eventImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var eventNameLabel: UILabel!
    var error:String?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
     }
}
```

I got:

> 'fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional
>   value"

on this line:

```
myEventcell.eventNameLabel.text = "hello"
```

Weird is that the "`print`" gives the following output:

```
<test.MyEventTableViewCell: 0x7dab0400; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7be738c0">>
```

What do we have to do to manage subclass of `UITableViewCell`?

PS: I am working with the storyboard to define my Custom cell and I am working with Xcode 7.

Comment: Can you do a print of `myEventCell.eventNameLabel`? Since you do get a print of the cell, we need to know if the `eventNameLabel` is populated since it's an implicitly unwrapped optional.

Comment: If I do: print(myEventCell) and print(myEventCell.eventNameLabel), I got the following output: <test.MyEventTableViewCell: 0x7e075a00; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c9995e0>>      and for the second print: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: That means your `eventNameLabel` outlet is not properly connected to the label on the view.

Comment: I tried again, did everything correctly, and this is not working. Did you try this in Swift? Do you have an example? Tx

Answer (score 4):

FirebaseUI developer here:

If you're using storyboards/prototype cells, use the constructor that has the `prototypeReuseIdentifier` vs the `cellReuseIdentifier` (see [here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseUI/Core/API/FirebaseTableViewDataSource.h#L121)). This is an unfortunate wart caused by how iOS started doing `UICollectionView`s but left the `UITableView` implementation of Storyboards different. TL;DR: Storyboards automatically register the cell reuse identifier for you, and if you try to register it again it'll override it and consider it different, meaning you don't see anything. See the FirebaseUI docs on [Using Storyboards and Prototype Cells](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS#using-storyboards-and-prototype-cells) for more info (though looks like I need to add in the prototype bit, so apologies for the confusion).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you forgot to implement init in your custom cell

For FirebaseUI-ios github

> Create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell or UICollectionViewCell, with or without the XIB file. Make sure to instantiate -initWithStyle: reuseIdentifier: to instantiate a UITableViewCell or -initWithFrame: to instantiate a UICollectionViewCell. You can then hook the custom class up to the implementation of FirebaseTableViewDataSource.

Comment: Can you please specify exactly what needs to be added to make this work? Can I still use the constraints defined in the storybaord? Thanks

Comment: oh !!, with storyboard, it should call awakeFromNib (as far as I know). Don't have any mac to test right now. In your storyboard, did you correctly set the custom class ? are your IBoulet correctly connected to the storyboard ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I thought. Yes, I set correctly the custom class (I check 2-3 times). Same for the IBOutlet ;)